# Позиционирование пунктов меню в Nav-Bar'e

Tags: bootstrap

У нас есть меню допустим оно определено следующим кодом:

```
<nav class="horizontal-nav full-width">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Navigation Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
```

Когда открываешь его в браузере будет приблизительно следующее: 
[image]

Подскажите пожалуйста, относительно чего и как нужно задавать в CSS размеры пунктов меню что бы они растянулись на всю отведенную область меню вот так: 
[image]

Мне важно понять принцип, относительно чего и как позиционировать т.к. как я понимаю его можно применять не только к меню.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Достаточно добавить css класс **nav-justified**

Пример можно посмотреть на [сайте официальной документации](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/justified-nav/)

Answer (score 1):

как вариант

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav > ul {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  background: #39909A;
  height: 50px;
}

nav > ul > li {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 50px;
}

nav > ul > li a {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0 30px;
}

nav > ul > li:hover a {
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<nav class="horizontal-nav full-width">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Navigation Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```